# view contents flagged by other users

Tags: 7, views, flags

I would like to make a view to select the contents flagged by a list of users.

I tried this:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1191228

but it works only for one user at time. ***I would need that for multiple users***.

In the "uid" contextual filter I tried to set "Allow multiple values" in the "more" area, but when I use more than one user ("uid1, uid2" or "uid1 + uid2"), the view is not ran.

any idea?

thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try to uncheck the "require this relationship" checkbox in the relationships of your view

Comment: OP didn't mention anywhere that he used relationship in the view. Is this your guess? ;) and in your answer you used the term 'unset' does it mean 'uncheck'?

Comment: You are right! is uncheck, not unset, I edited the answer. And is not my guess ;), you can read the referenced tutorial, specifically this comment https://www.drupal.org/node/1191228#comment-4708174

Comment: You are right, there is a relationship. Unfortunately I did not check the "require this relationship" option.